# Why do I get an error when I pass RandomAccessFile.writeUTF these parameters?

Tags: java

```
ManageStock2.java:104: error: method writeUTF in class RandomAccessFile cannot b
e applied to given types;
                                        in.writeUTF(authors , titles ,ISBN);
                                          ^
  required: String
  found: String,String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

I have initialized the variables already.

```
String ISBN,ISBN2,authors,titles; 
int levels,level2,stock;
```

I need to know what to write. I have checked the api already.

Comment: What part of the error message didn't you understand?

Comment: And are you 100% sure that a RAF is what you should be using here?

Comment: yep 100 % sure (hovercraft).
i dont know why it is accepting in.writeUTF(authors etc.)(meriton)

Answer (score 2):

The function [takes one argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29), and you're supplying three. Split the call into three:

```
in.writeUTF(authors);
in.writeUTF(titles);
in.writeUTF(ISBN);
```

This writes the three strings one after another. If you want to apply formatting (e.g. field separators etc), you could use `StringBuilder` or `String.format()`.

Comment: @AndrewO'Neill In the code you have multiple calls as you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, you invoked `writeUTF` with **three** arguments, but it takes **[only one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29)**:

> public final void `writeChars(String s)`
>                         throws IOException
>
> Writes a string to the file as a sequence of characters. Each character is written to the data output stream as if by the `writeChar` method. The write starts at the current position of the file pointer.

Instead, make three separate calls:

```
in.writeUTF(authors);
in.writeUTF(titles);
in.writeUTF(ISBN);
```